# How to make column heights equal in Boostrap4 with embed?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, height

I'm working to create an interactive web interface, and I have a row in bootstrap with two columns. One column contains an "embed-responsive-16by9" and the other has a ul that I don't know the height of. How would I be able to make the column with the ul stay the height of the embed, overflowing if it is larger but not going less if it is smaller?

I've tried ".row-eq-height", setting max-height, etc. but nothing seems to be working.

```
<div className="container-fluid">
  <div className="row h-40 row-eq-height">
    <div className="col">
      <div className="rounded resize shadow-sm">
        <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe
              className="embed-responsive-item"
              src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RHXsHZMBIcQ"
              title="Video Player"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="pl-2 pt-2">
          <input className="mr-1" type="checkbox" />
          <label>Autoplay?</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="col">
      <ul className="list-group container float-left rounded p-0 mr-auto eq-col min-vw-30 max-vw-80 resize shadow-sm">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-light navbar-right bg-light m-2 p-1">
          <h1 className="navbar-brand">Watched Teams</h1>
          <div className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input
              className="form-control mr-sm-2"
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search"
            />
            <button
              className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0"
              type="submit"
            >
              Search
            </button>
          </div>
        </nav>
        {this.state.teams.map(team => (
          <Team key={team.teamNum} team={team} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

BTW I am doing this all through react, so this is somewhat separated as it's in multiple components, but this is all put together for the sake of the post.

SOLUTION: The key was using h-100 and flex-grow-1...I had tried both before, but I guess not on the ul element directly.
`<ul className="h-100 list-group container float-left rounded p-0 mr-auto eq-col min-vw-30 max-vw-80 shadow-sm flex-grow-1">`

Comment: className why ?

Comment: I'm writing this using React, so technically it is in JSX not JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was using h-100 and flex-grow-1...I had tried both before, but I guess not on the ul element directly. 
`<ul className="h-100 list-group container float-left rounded p-0 mr-auto eq-col min-vw-30 max-vw-80 shadow-sm flex-grow-1">`